# I have my PHP server running, but how do I get to a php file on it?

Tags: php, curl

I started my php server with `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080` and I visited on http://localhost:8080/ which just show "Not found" and "The requested resource / was not found on this server." Now I would like to run a file called curly.php which contains a cURL command that I normally use to get JSON back from a server. I'm doing this so that I can write a test. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried visiting http://localhost:8080/curly.php ? have you started php in the right directory?

Comment: If you want something to show at http://localhost:8080/, you need a file named `index.php`

Comment: No I hadn't Franz, thank you :) and thanks ordonezalex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server runs from the current working directory from which PHP was started. This is the document root and all scripts are served from there.  The path should show up in the console when you start PHP.

```
$ php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

The terminal will show something like

```
PHP 5.4.0 Development Server started at Thu Jul 21 10:43:28 2011
Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
Document root is /path/to/root
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

In this example, `/path/to/root` is the doc root. To access your script,

1. create a new folder within the doc root and call is something like `scripts`.
2. In this new folder, place your `curly.php`
3. Start the PHP server `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t scripts/`.  this will now make your new folder the doc root.
4. Go to the script in your browser: `http://localhost:8080/curly.php`

**Bonus**

If you want a default "home" page to open when you go to `http://localhost:8080`, just add a file named `index.php` in your `/scripts` folder